# How to do Dependency Injection of entities into a repository if those entities have required arguments for construction?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, entities

How do I do Dependency Injection of entities into a repository if those entities have required arguments for construction?

Take this simple example (in PHP, but question is language agnostic):

**Person Entity**

```
class Person
{
    private $firstName = "";
    private $middleName = "";
    private $lastName = "";
    private $dateOfBirth;
    private $dateOfDeath;

    public function __construct($firstName, $middleName = "", $lastName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->middleName = $middleName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        // Validation
        if(empty($this->firstName) || empty($this->lastName){
            throw new Exception("first and last name required");
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Person Repository**

```
class PersonRepository
{
    public function __construct(Person $person)  // <-- problem, need required arguments
    {
         $this->person = $person;
    }

    public function fetchById($id)
    {
         // Query database
         // ...

         // Hydrate and return a person object
         // ...

         return $person;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So what am I missing? What is the standard approach to inject the entity and avoid using the `new` operator in the repository?

Comment: Reflection is usually used so that the entity can be instantiated without calling the business constructor and then every private fields are set through reflection. However in your case, why can't you just do return `new Person(dataset.firstName, ...)`?

Comment: Take a look at how Doctrine 2 does it.  Constructors are never called when hydrating from the database.  And yes, it uses reflection to accomplish the task.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: Why would you inject a `Person` into the repositories constructor anyways?

Comment: @AlexanderLanger Many repositories are going to be 1:1 with their entity. So injecting that entity in the constructor makes sense. Right? @Cerad I've looked at Doctrine 2 before and I want to have full control over how I hydrate my objects. But I'll look at it again and see how they are using Reflection there. @plalx I was trying to avoid a `new` for easier testing/mocking.

Comment: @Cerad that's interesting that constructors are not used when populating from the database. However, sometimes you have a form where you enter data to create a NEW entity, so you would need a constructor.

Comment: Of course you still need a constructor when new'ing an entity.  Your sample Person::_construct is fine.  It's just that the constructor is not used during hydration so your reflection based database operations do not need to worry about it.  What you do during your form processing is not relevant for this question.  Maybe take a look at the Symfony forms component for ideas on that.

Comment: I'm with Alexander, even if the repository is 1:1 you shouldn't inject it in constructor. The instantiation of the class should be delegated to a class `Manager` not a repository, you could then inject that manager in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about "Abstract Factory". It's a pattern.

```
class PersonRepository
{
    public function __construct(PersonFactory $factory){
         $this->personFactory = $factory;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
         // ...
         return $this->personFactory->create($row['name'], $row['surname'], ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't think about a factory. And this looks good for testing too. Brilliant @Abe!